# Examples of a statistic that is not independent of sample's distribution?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, definition

This is the definition for **statistic** on wikipedia

> More formally, statistical theory defines a statistic as a function of a sample where the function itself is independent of the sample's distribution; that is, the function can be stated before realization of the data. The term statistic is used both for the function and for the value of the function on a given sample.

I think I understand most of this definition, however the part - *where the function is independent of the sample's distribution* I haven't been able to sort out.

**My understanding of statistic so far**

A **sample** is a set of realizations of some number of independent, identically distributed (iid) random variables with distribution F (10 realizations of a roll of a 20-sided fair dice, 100 realizations of 5 rolls of a 6-sided fair dice, randomly draw 100 people from a population).

A function, whose domain is that set, and whose range is the real numbers (or maybe it can produce other things, like a vector or other mathematical object...) would be considered a **statistic**.

When I think of examples, mean, median, variance all make sense in this context. They are a function on set of realizations (blood pressure measurements from a random sample). I can also see how a linear regression model could be considered a statistic $y_{i} = \alpha + \beta \cdot x_{i}$ - is this not just a function on a set of realizations?

**Where I'm confused**

Assuming that my understanding from above is correct, I haven't been able to understand where a function might not be independent of the sample's distribution. I've been trying to think of an example to make sense of it, but no luck. Any insight would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

That definition is a somewhat awkward way to state it.  A "statistic" is any function of the observable values.  All that definition means is that a statistic is a function only of the observable values, not a function of the distribution or any of its parameters.  For example, if $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n \sim \text{N}(\mu, 1)$ then a statistic would be any function $T(X_1,...,X_n)$ whereas a function $H(X_1,....,X_n, \mu)$ would not be a statistic, since it depends on $\mu$.  Here are some further examples:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\text{Statistic} & & & & & \bar{X}_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i, \\[12pt]
\text{Statistic} & & & & & S_n^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X}_n)^2, \\[12pt]
\text{Not a statistic} & & & & & D_n = \bar{X}_n - \mu, \\[12pt]
\text{Not a statistic} & & & & & p_i = \text{N}(x_i | \mu, 1), \\[12pt]
\text{Not a statistic} & & & & & Q = 10 \mu. \\[12pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Every statistic is a function only of the observable values, and not of their distribution or its parameters.  So there are no examples of a statistic that is a function of the distribution or its parameters (any such function would not be a statistic).  However, it is important to note that the *distribution of a statistic* (as opposed to the statistic itself) will generally depend on the underlying distribution of the values.  (This is true for all statistics other than [ancillary statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancillary_statistic).)

---

**What about a function where the parameters are known?** In the comments below, [Alecos](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/28746/alecos-papadopoulos) asks an excellent follow-up question.  What about a function that uses a fixed hypothesised value of the parameter?  For example, what about the statistic $\sqrt{n} (\bar{x} - \mu)$ where $\mu = \mu_0$ is taken to be equal to a known hypothesised value $\mu_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.  Here the function is indeed a statistic, so long as it is defined on the appropriately restricted domain. So the function $H_0: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $H_0(x_1,...,x_n) = \sqrt{n} (\bar{x} - \mu_0)$ would be a statistic, but the function $H: \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $H(x_1,...,x_n, \mu) = \sqrt{n} (\bar{x} - \mu)$ would **not** be a statistic.

Comment: Very helpful answer, considering the underlying statistical parameter as part of the non-statistic was particularly helpful.

Comment: Sadly,  InRealLife(TM), the opposite occurs: people claim valid statistics despite leaving out several of the $X_i$

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I don't get your point. If it's a function of the observable values, then it's a statistic. It may be a function of a smaller subset of the values; that can still be a useful thing to consider. If you want to estimate the mean and you have $10^{10}$ observations, you might still look at $(X_1+X_2+\dots+X_{1000})/1000$ if the cost of processing data is high and the cost of error is small. Or for some reason you might want to consider two independent estimates of the mean, and could consider $(X_1+\dots+X_{n/2})/(n/2)$ and $(X_{n/2+1}+\dots+X_n)/(n/2)$. These are still statistics.

Comment: Or indeed many real-life applications involve dividing the data into, say, a training set and a validation set. Statistics depending on, say, the training set alone could obviously be of interest.

Comment: @JamesMartin  emphasis on the word "valid" :-)

Comment: Those examples seem entirely valid to me. Are you saying the idea of dividing data into a training set and a validation set is not valid?

Comment: I'm a little confused by that as well. Let me attempt to describe @CarlWitthoft point. It would still be a statistic in terms of mathematical definition, but I could see a case where a consultant takes a 'statistic' of observations, but arbitrarily decides to remove a few results (consultants do this all the time right?). This would be 'valid' in the sense it's still a function on observations, however the way that statistic may be presented and interpreted likely wouldn't be valid.

Comment: A question for you Ben: Is $\sqrt{n}(\bar x - \mu)$ a statistic, _under a specific null hypothesis that fixes the value of $\mu$_?

Comment: @Alecos: It would indeed be a statistic so long as the function itself is defined on the appropriately restricted domain.  So the function, $T: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $T(x_1,...,x_n) = \sqrt{n} (\bar{x} - \mu)$ (where $\mu$ is a known constant) would be a statistic.

Comment: @Carl Withhoft: With respect to the point you are making, it is important to distinguish between a *statistic* (which need not include all the data, and may not encompass all the information in the sample) and a *sufficient statistic* (which will encompass all the information with respect to some parameter).  Statistical theory already has well-developed concepts like sufficiency that capture the idea that a statistic includes all relevant information in the sample.  It is not necessary, or desirable, to try to build that requirement into the definition of a "statistic".

Comment: I believe @CarlWitthoft is merely making a point about cherry-picking data. Technically, this still could still follow the original description of a statistic; your original function is that you will drop all data you don't like and then compute a measure on that subset of data.

Comment: @Cliff: There is no "technically" about it.  There is nothing at all in the concept of a "statistic" that requires it to use all the data.  Any discussion of "cherry picking" is completely misplaced when talking about the definition of a statistic.  You can have a statistic that depends on all the data, or half the data, or one data point, or no data points (i.e., a constant).

Comment: I think Carl's joke is in reference to this part of the quote in the original post: "the function can be stated before realization of the data". He's making a joke about the fact that many researchers look at the data and *then decide what function to use*, and report their statistic as though it was what they planned on looking at from the beginning.

Comment: @Cliff: I don't see any joke, so we'll have to agree to disagree.  In any case, none of that has anything to do with the definition of a statistic.

Comment: Fair enough. To clear, I don't think it's suppose to disagree with what anyone here is saying is the definition of what a statistic is, it's just supposed to be a poke at bad statistical practices, i.e., p-hacking, dropping inconvenient data, etc. (+1 to the answer, btw)

Comment: @Ben this might constitute a separate question, but you touch on this in your follow-up to Alecos so I'll ask here first. Are there any restrictions on domain or range, or combinations of domains/ranges? For example - can you call a function whose domain is the set of circles and range is a vector a statistic? What about functions whose domain is the set of parallelepipeds and range is another function? These are contrived examples, but I'm just tying to play with the idea a bit more

Comment: @Jake: So long as those domains you have specified come from the data, and not some aspect of the distribution/parameters, that would still be okay.  So, for example, if the data points are circles and your function maps from the allowable set of circles to the real numbers, that would be a statistic.  Of course, usually the data would be expressed in its simplest numerical form, so a circular data point would usually be given by an origin value and radius, rather than being the actual circle.  Still, there is no reason in principle that it could not be framed that way.  ...

Comment: ...  Now, bear in mind that functions of data are random variables whenever the data is a random variable (as discussed in [your other question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/396815/)).  This requires that the relevant functions be "measureable" with respect to the underlying probability measure on your sample space, but this is a pretty light requirement.

Answer (score 4):

I interpret that as saying that you should decide before you see the data what statistic you are going to calculate. So, for instance, if you're going to take out outliers, you should decide before you see the data what constitutes an "outlier". If you decide after you see the data, then your function is dependent on the data.

Comment: this is also helpful! So making a decision on which observations to include in the function after knowing what observations are available, which is more or less what I was describing in my comment on the previous answer.

Comment: (+1) It might be worth noting that this important because if you define a rule a prior about what constitutes a data point that will be dropped, it is (relatively) easy to derive a distribution for statistic (i.e., truncated mean, etc.). It's really hard to derive a distribution for a measure that involves dropping data points for reasons that are not cleanly defined before hand.