# Random variable vs Statistic?

Tags: random-variable, definition

What's the difference between a random variable and a statistic?

It seems that formally, a random variable is simply any real-valued function (and its domain is a set that we call a "sample space").

But isn't the exact same also true of a statistic? That is, isn't a statistic also simply any real-valued function (whose domain is a set called a "sample space")?

---

**Example.** We roll a die. The sample space is $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Let $T$ be double the value of the die roll: Formally, $T:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is the function defined by $T(x)=2x$.

Is $T$ a random variable, a statistic, or both?

---

In your answer, please give:

1. A precise definition of a random variable
2. A precise definition of a statistic
3. An answer to the question in my example: "Is $T$ a random variable, a statistic, or both?"

Comment: I had a [similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/396944/definition-of-statistic). According to the answer I got, they are fairly different

Answer (score 9):

A statistic is a function defined over one or more random variables.

So yes, a statistic **is** a random variable, and follows a distribution.

Another answer gave the example of the mean of a bunch of iid normal random variables.
$X_1,...,X_n\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$

The mean **is** a statistic because it is a function defined over random variables
$$\bar{X}= g(X_1, X_2 ... X_n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i $$

There is one condition however, which is that a statistic cannot explicitly depend on unknown parameters. Take the following definition of $g$ :

$$ g(X_1) = \frac{X_1 - \mu}{\sigma}$$

While $g$ here is a function of a random variable, and it follows a standard normal distribution, it's **not** a statistic (unless $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are known).

For a more detailed explanation see pg. 122 of [this](https://fac.ksu.edu.sa/sites/default/files/hogg_craig_-_introduction_to_mathematical_statistics_4th_edition1.pdf).

Comment: So in my example, is $T$ a random variable, a statistic, or both?

Comment: Technically, both. The difference lies in what you are intending to do with it. Like Scortchi mentioned in another answer, you'd call it a statistic if you're intending to perform inference/estimation. In your case, $T$ doesn't seem to be an estimate of an unknown parameter, so just call it a random variable.

Answer (score 6):

The definition of a random variable depends on the context because how precise you need the definition to be depends on what kind of math you are doing. In the simplest definition, a *random variable*  $X: \Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function from a set of possible outcomes $\Omega$ onto the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$. For example, in the case of a coin, $\Omega = \lbrace H,T\rbrace$, you might have $H=1$ and $T=0$. The *probability distribution* carries all the info about the probabilities.

A *statistic* is a quantity computed from a sample. In statistical theories, usually these samples are themselves random variables. So the statistic itself is a random variable. For instance, if

$$X_1,...,X_n\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$$
then the sample mean is also a random variable
$$\bar{X}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i $$
$$\bar{X}\sim N\left(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\right)$$

However, in practice, people may differ whether they consider a statistic to refer to a random variable.

Comment: Perhaps you don't mean precisely what you seem to say, and there is scope for narrow and wide definitions, but in my mind a random variable isn't limited to functions with range the real line, or even subsets of it. I have no problems with the idea that say a scatter plot is a random variable depending on samples from a bivariate distribution.

Comment: So, what is your definition of a statistic?

Comment: I disagree with the definition given in this answer. It seems to confuse random variables with their realized values. The formal definition of a statistic defines it as a random variable. If the data have happened, then the number calculated is the realized value of a random variable.

Comment: I've tried to adjust my answer to incorporate the constructive criticism in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The key thing is that a statistic is not a function of unknown parameters; so not all random variables are statistics. See [Examples of a statistic that is not independent of sample's distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/396815/17230). And note that the distribution of a statistic may depend on unknown parameters; cf. a pivot, a random variable whose distribution does not depend on unknown parameters, though it may be a function of unknown parameters.

That something is a statistic doesn't mean you have to call it one: in applications the term tends to be reserved for random variables that play a special rôle in inference or description, & typically reduce the dimensionality of the sample space. Your *T* is a random variable; & also a statistic, even though no such motivation for using the latter term is evident.